# Assembly LINUX, x86-64 - Calling convention

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, stack, x86-64

I am currently learning the basics of assembly language for LINUX OS, x84-64 processors, GCC compilers and I came across an example which tries to translate into assembly the following C function:

```
unsigned long fact(unsigned n)
{
 if (n<=1) 
    return 1;
 else 
    return n*fact(n-1);
}
```

This is the solution proposed:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.text
.global fact
.type fact, @function
fact:      PUSH RBP
           MOV RBP, RSP
           CMP EDI, 1
           JBE retour_un
           PUSH RDI
           DEC RDI
           SUB RSP, 8
           CALL fact
           ADD RSP, 8
           POP RDI
           MUL RDI
           JMP retour
retour_un: MOV RAX, 1
retour:    POP RBP
           RET
```

However, I don't exactly how this works. From what I have read the CALL instruction places on the stack the value of RIP and then jumps to wherever its argument shows. In this case, I understand up to the point where CALL fact is used. If this instruction is implemented everytime then everytime the program will start form the beginning until RDI==1 in which case it will jump to retour_un and everything that there is in between will never be executed. Could someone explain to me where I am mistaken and how this segment of assembly code actually works?

Comment: `ret` will of course continue the execution after the `call` so those instructions will be executed. Use a debugger to single step the code and you will see.

Comment: Okeei, this makes sense now. Thanks a lot.